# Вопрос об обновлении VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Решил поставить себе VS Code на ПК, была версия 1.25, обновление пришло на 1.26. Думал, что заместятся старые файлы на новые и скачал архив, распаковал, но скачался новый файл VSC независимый, что с этими двумя версиями делать - соединять в папку одну, удалить старую версию, что делать с расширениями?

Comment: **vscode обновляется автоматически (по умолчанию)**, ничего делать не нужно вообще. Обновление будет предложено при старте/запуске программы. Сейчас обновления выходят примерно 1 раз в месяц.

Comment: А тогда почему при проверке и дальнейшей установки у меня скачался архив весом как и прошлая версия?

Comment: при обновлении файлы приложения полностью заменяются. Если вы выбираете нестандартные пути установки, то возможно дублирование директорий. Пользуюсь VSCode с бета-версии и всё работает как надо (MAC, Windows 10, Linux)

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На верхней панели нажимаете 
1) 'Справка' -> 'Проверить наличие обновлений',
2) Внизу справа появится окошко 'обновить'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так все сделал, меня перекинуло на браузер, скачалась последняя версия архивом, в итоге имею два файла VSC двух версий, старую удалить не получается, расширения слетают вообще при удалении старой версии? или надо просто слить все файлы в одной папке?

Comment: Похожая ситуация.
VS Code 1.26 стоит и тут появляется окно с текстом:
"We recommend switching to our new User Setup distribution of Code for Windows! Click here to learn more."
Однако переходя по Click here вижу информацию о версии 1.25

Comment: при "мажорных" обновлениях такое часто и не только с VSCode

Comment: А после такого обновления мне расширения заново устанавливать не придется с параметрами?

Comment: Как вообще отключить обновление Visual Code?